# A science fiction (maybe kids) book about a TV remote working as a time machine

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I read this book a really long time ago (likely 18-24 years ago). A kid goes to his grandmother's house and the grandmother says she accidentally made the TV remote into a time machine that can pause, rewind and fast forward time. The kid takes it and almost rewinds to before he was born and gets into other trouble. In the end, the kid destroys the remote by dropping it into a pot of soup. The kid's name might be Karen, but I am pretty sure it is a boy.

Comment: How long was a really long time ago? Was it new at the time?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot At least 20 years ago, but it probably wasn't new then.